# Issues going from grails 1.0.x to 1.1.2

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I have a code taht I am working on that was last worked on some time ago. It was an earlier version of grails (but I am not sure which) and I had to run the grails-upgrade command for it.

Now when I do grails run-app, i get the following:
[groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed, General error during semantic analysis: unable to locate the java compiler com.sun.tools.javac.Main, please change your classloader settings

What does this mean exactly, and how do I fix it? Is it actually a groovy problem? I googled the error message but didnt find much.

Thanks@

Comment: Did you check your JAVA_HOME settings?

Comment: Yes - I also tried to install the latest version of grails to make sure that wasnt the problem, and the old version from the projects inception - still got the issue there too.

Comment: are you sure you're pointing to a JDK install and not a JRE install?

Comment: Also, create a brand new application (grails create-app) using the latest version and see if that starts. If it does, do a diff on all of the config files versus the real app and see what's different. And check the compatibility for all of your plugins to make sure they work with the newest version.

Comment: what does "java -version" print?

Comment: So after fooling around with it - I set my JAVA_HOME to a 1.5JDK and the problem magically went away. Iam not sure what the problem was exactly - Maybe that version of groovyc only worked with a 1.5 JVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Java version, and not groovy. The original code was written and compiled with 1.5. I switched the JDK from 1.6 to 1.5 and it worked.